# In probability, is it a subset if the experiment has been repeated more times but the first results are the same?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let's say that I flip a coin three times and get 3 heads. I then flip the same coin 5 times and get 3 heads followed by two tails.

Is $\{HHH\}$ a subset of $\{HHHTT\}$. If not, why not?

I apologize if the question seems trivial.

Comment: In the experiments described in the OP, the sample spaces are entirely different, so neither of your events is a subset of the other. But if you toss a coin $3$ times, then the event "heads on the first two tosses" is a subset of the event "head on the second toss."

Comment: We can assume that he takes as sample spaces all results for tossing a coin any number of times. Sure, the OP does not seem to know about probability spaces and tribes; but his question seems to be a basic one, he just wants to know about inclusion between events. No need to confuse him imo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather $\lbrace HHHTT\rbrace \subset \lbrace HHH\rbrace$. Indeed, if you are in $\lbrace HHHTT\rbrace$, then you are in $\lbrace HHH\rbrace$ because your first three tosses are heads. 
On the contrary, you can be in $\lbrace HHH\rbrace$ without being in $\lbrace HHHTT\rbrace$ : you can have 3 heads, then another one for instance. 
So $\lbrace HHHTT\rbrace \subset \lbrace HHH\rbrace$.

In short words, subsets of an event $A$ are events that imply $A$.